# Form with status bar

Tags: javascript, html, forms, counter, statusbar

On my website I need to make some kind of test. It has 5 questions and a status bar on the end. Each question has 2 possible answers (1 negative and 1 positive).

The status bar indicator starts in the middle and depending on the answers the indicator goes to the left or right.

Example:

```
    < .  .  .  .  .  |  .  .  .  .  .  >
negative                            positive
```

I think I can achieve this with some kind of step counter in JavaScript,
but I really don't know how to make this.

Please someone help me!

Below is the code of my questions.

```
<div class ="test">
<form>

<div class="testTitel">Titel1</div>
<div id="demo" class="collapse in">

<input type="radio" name="group1" value="G a"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Restinguet citius, si ardentem acceperit. <br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="G b"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Restinguet citius, si ardentem acceperit. <br>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo,#demo2">
  NEXT
</button>
</div>
<div class="testTitel">Titel2</div>
<div id="demo2" class="collapse">

<input type="radio" name="group2" value="F a"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Restinguet citius, si ardentem acceperit. <br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="F b"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Restinguet citius, si ardentem acceperit. <br>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo,#demo2">
  BACK
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2,#demo3">
  NEXT
</button>
</div>
<div class="testTitel">Titel3</div>
<div id="demo3" class="collapse">

<input type="radio" name="group3" value="O a"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Restinguet citius, si ardentem acceperit. <br>
<input type="radio" name="group3" value="O b"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Restinguet citius, si ardentem acceperit. <br>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2,#demo3">
  BACK
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo3,#demo4">
  NEXT
</button>
</div>
<div class="testTitel">Titel4</div>
<div id="demo4" class="collapse">

<input type="radio" name="group4" value="W a"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Restinguet citius, si ardentem acceperit. <br>
<input type="radio" name="group4" value="W b"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Restinguet citius, si ardentem acceperit. <br>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo3,#demo4">
  BACK
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo4,#demo5">
  NEXT
</button>
</div>
<div class="testTitel">Titel5</div>
<div id="demo5" class="collapse">

<input type="radio" name="group5" value="I a"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Restinguet citius, si ardentem acceperit. <br>
<input type="radio" name="group5" value="I b"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Restinguet citius, si ardentem acceperit. <br>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo4,#demo5">
  BACK
</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that I worked up based on your question.

I created a HTML meter element that consisted of a DIV nested inside of another DIV.

```
<div id="qust_indicator">
  <div id="dial"></div>
</div>
```

I then created some simple styling for the meter. The CSS style that we want to focus on is the #dial margin-left. I will be used to move the dial left and right.

```
#qust_indicator {
    background:blue;
    height: 5px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    width: 340px;
}

#dial {
    background:red;
    height: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    margin-left: 160px;
}
```

Using jQuery, this is the code that does all the magic stuff.

```
// create a variable for the form inputs
var $textRadioBtn = $('.test input[type="radio"]');

// radio button click event
$textRadioBtn.click(function () {

    // get the margin-left CSS value of the meeter dail
    var getDialmrLft = $('#dial').css('margin-left');

    // strip out the px from the margin-left CSS value 
    var strDialmrLft = getDialmrLft.replace('px', '');

    // convert the  margin-left CSS value to a number
    var NumDialmrLft = Number(strDialmrLft);

    // get the value of the checkbox ( 1 or 2 )
    var inptVal = this.value;

    // check to see if the checkbox value is 1 and less than the meter max value
    if ( inptVal == 1 && NumDialmrLft < 320 ) {

        // disable the selected checkbox
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        // enable the selected checkbox’s siblings
        $(this).siblings('input').prop('disabled', false);

        //set the incrementing value
        var newPos = NumDialmrLft + 20;
        // set the new margin-left CSS value and move the meter dail
        $('#dial').attr('style', 'margin-left:'+newPos+'px');
    // check to see if the checkbox value is 2 and greater than 0 value
    } else if ( inptVal == 2 && NumDialmrLft > 0 ) {

        // disable the selected checkbox
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        // enable the selected checkbox’s siblings
        $(this).siblings('input').prop('disabled', false);

        //set the de-incrementing value
        var newPos = NumDialmrLft - 20;
        // set the new margin-left CSS value and move the meter dail
        $('#dial').attr('style', 'margin-left:'+newPos+'px');
    }
});
```

Comment: How to do it with % and not px?
i want it to make it responsive, already tried to change all px to %, didnt work

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you wanted a status indicator bar. Which will mean moving the bar left or right based on the question answers. Meaning if you answer more positive answer then the dial would farther in that direction. I a negative answer is placed in the process then the dial would more one place to the negative side but still be in the positive area until there are more negative answers than positive.

you can expand the number of ticks to match the number of questions you have by multiplying the total area of the indicator minus the width of the dial. in my example the width of the #qust_indicator is 340px and the dial is 20px. So the conditional if statement are looking for a max positive margin-left property of 320px for the dial.